# Scan Wifi Networks via objective-c in a Mac OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, network-programming, wifi

Is there a tutorial available which explains how to scan for available wifi networks via Objective-C in a mac app? I have been searching for the past few days but only found bonjour related results. I read that CoreWLAN framework is used for wifi scanning and communication, could anyone please guide me in this regards?
I just want to create a program which scans for available wifi routers around. And then when I click on any of the router, it gives me a list of devices attached with that router. Is it possible?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's Developer site has a nice sample project [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008921-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which seems to explain using code what you're looking for - there's also a somewhat old tutorial [here](http://dougturner.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/usingcorewlan/), though it may still help you along.

Comment: Wow!! That was great. Thanks a lot Andrew. I will ping you in case of any problem i come across. :-) Thanks once again.

Comment: Andrew, can i get the list of devices connected to a wifi router? Thanks

Comment: Probably not - you could possible do a scan of the local subnet to see if any devices respond to icmp ping or something, but that's about it, and that could be potentially ridiculous depending on the IP assigned to your machine.