# Be notified when network is available

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

I am wondering, is there a way to be notified of the availability of a desired network while being connected to a different one?

Trying to explain myself. I am connected with my Mac to network A. Is there a way to be notified that network B has become available?

Being able to afterward connect to network B would be awesome too.

EDIT.

I think what I am looking for is an equivalent of the `broadcastReceiver` in Android, but I can not find anything related to Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045291/scan-wifi-networks-via-objective-c-in-a-mac-os-x-app), Apple has a sample project for a [Wifi scanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Listings/CoreWLANController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008921-CoreWLANController_m-DontLinkElementID_4). Inspect the code and you will find the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I will surely check out the link you proposed.